# rotate and store the rotation of a image in a php/mysql website?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, image

i am creating an photo uploading website and i want the users to upload their images.

uploading is done, no problem, BUT,

some images taken with the camera held vertically so the image looks like this:

```
 http://s30.postimg.org/o5tqpg4dd/like_a_boss_Copy.jpg
```

i want to give users the option so they can rotate the image clock-wise or counter-clock-wise so the image can appear like this:

```
  http://s12.postimg.org/hhimt7v59/like_a_boss.jpg
```

how to store the saved rotation of the user, so when the image is opened the next time it is in the correct angle?

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use php to rotate the images. You don't have to store the rotation value, just edit (transform, rotate) the image at the first time and save the edited image to you server.

```
resource imagerotate ( resource $image , float $angle , int $bgd_color [, int $ignore_transparent = 0 ] )
```